# jq with json Cannot index string with string "version"

Tags: json, shell, jq

Sample Json

```
{
  "product": [
    {
      "versions": "1.0",
      "components": [
        {
          "name": "JVM",
          "version": "11.0.16"
        },
        {
          "name": "TOMCAT",
          "version": "9.0.56"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "versions": "1.1",
      "components": [
        {
          "name": "JVM",
          "version": "11.0.16"
        },
        {
          "name": "TOMCAT",
          "version": "9.0.56"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Command

```
jq -r '.product[] | .versions, .components[] | "\(.name): \(.version)"' version_mapper.json
```

Output

```
jq: error (at version_mapper.json:29): Cannot index string with string "version"
```

Wrong Command

```
jq -r '.product[] | .wrongKey, .components[] | "\(.name): \(.version)"' version_mapper.json
```

Output

```
null: null
JVM: 11.0.16
TOMCAT: 9.0.56
null: null
JVM: 11.0.16
TOMCAT: 9.0.56
```

Not sure what is happening

Comment: just remove the `.versions` from the filter, I don't think you want that part? (`.versions` filter produces the strings, not objects)

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the `.versions` if you want each components `name` and `version` this is enough:

```
.product[].components[] | "\(.name): \(.version)"
```

Output

```
JVM: 11.0.16
TOMCAT: 9.0.56
JVM: 11.0.16
TOMCAT: 9.0.56
```

---

If you want to include the `versions` from the product themself, you can loop over the components after showing `.versions`, for example the following filter

```
.product[] | .versions, (.components[] | "\t\(.name): \(.version)")
```

Outputs

```
1.0
    JVM: 11.0.16
    TOMCAT: 9.0.56
1.1
    JVM: 11.0.16
    TOMCAT: 9.0.56
```

---

If you don't need the string interpolation, `"\(.name): \(.version)"` can be replaced with `join(": ")`, eg:

```
.product[].components[] | join(": ")
```